# 2 selected objects - what context menu to display?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, menu, contextual-menu

I have a similar question to [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72581/remove-or-disable-context-menu-items-with-multiple-selected-items).

I have 2 different types of objects. When you click on Object A you get a list of contextual menu items available. When you click on Object B you get another list of contextual menu items available.

Some of these functions may be the same (e.g. **Show**) and that works perfectly well on both objects.

Some functions only apply to Object A (e.g. **Edit**). Some functions only apply to Object B (e.g. **Properties**).

I know you should remove/disable items that don't make sense, but if I did select both Object A and B and then clicked on **Edit** or **Properties** it would complete successfully - just not for both objects.

Do you think you should only display options that will complete successfully for both? That is, only show **Show** on the context menu when both objects are selected?

*Adding*: I have tried this with Windows Explorer and the behavior changes depending on which object type you clicked last. Is that expected?

*Adding*: Uploading screenshot which shows Windows Explorer behavior - multiple selected objects show different context menus depending on the order of the objects selected. Common functions are not the only ones to show up. The contextual menus also show functions that only relate to one object.

[image]

Comment: upload the mocks, they will help us understand it well.

Answer (score 1):

Show only options that are applicable for all selected objects, otherwise users will be very confused and make mistakes. This is the standard behavior in almost all applications, and it is an expected behavior.

To make your list more usable, you may provide them with a type sorting, so that users will easily select all items of one type and apply an option that is not available in the other type.